# Is there a way to get the real size / position of Image in a FittedBox?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a simple layout with an Image widget encapsulated in a FittedBox. I want to take it's size and position so I put a key on Image widget and get it from the initState:

```
final GlobalKey imgKey = GlobalKey();



@override
void initState() {
  SchedulerBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) async {
    await ModalRoute.of(context)?.didPush(); //wait opening transition
    final keyPosContext = imgKey.currentContext;
    if (keyPosContext != null){
      final renderPlan = keyPosContext.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
      final pos = renderPlan.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
      if(pos != planOffset || renderPlan.size != planSize) {
        setState(() {
          planOffset = pos;
          planSize = renderPlan.size;
        });
      }
    }
  });
  super.initState();
}
```

the layout:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context){
  return Stack(
    children: [
      Positioned(
        top: 0, left: 100, right: 100, height: 30,
        child: Align(alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text('$title'),
        ), 
      ),  
      Positioned(
        top: 30, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0,
        child: DragTarget<DraggableData>(
          onMove: onMove,
          onAccept: onAccept,
          builder: (BuildContext context, List candidateData, List rejectedData) {
            File img = File(myPlan);
            if (img.existsSync()) {
              return FittedBox(
                fit: BoxFit.contain,
                child: Image.file(img, key: imgKey),
              );
            } else
              return Container();
          }
        ),
      ),
      Positioned(//TEST
        top: planOffset.dy,
        left: planOffset.dx,
        height: planSize.height,
        width: planSize.width,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.green, width: 2),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ]
  );
}
```

The last Positioned is just a green rect to test the values. I take the right position but the size is wrong: I take the original image size (400*300 in my case)  regardless of the fitted size...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could can use this widget to get the size at run time.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

typedef void OnWidgetSizeChange(Size size);

class MeasureSize extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  final OnWidgetSizeChange onChange;

  const MeasureSize({Key? key, required this.onChange, required Widget child}) : super(key: key, child: child);

  @override
  RenderObject createRenderObject(BuildContext context) => _MeasureSizeRenderObject(onChange);
}

class _MeasureSizeRenderObject extends RenderProxyBox {
  Size? oldSize;
  final OnWidgetSizeChange onChange;

  _MeasureSizeRenderObject(this.onChange);

  @override
  void performLayout() {
    super.performLayout();

    Size newSize = child!.size;
    // if (oldSize == newSize) return;

    oldSize = newSize;
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) => onChange(newSize));
  }
}
```

To get the size

```
      ...
      Positioned(
        top: 30, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0,
        child: DragTarget<DraggableData>(
          onMove: onMove,
          onAccept: onAccept,
          builder: (BuildContext context, List candidateData, List rejectedData) {
            File img = File(myPlan);
            if (img.existsSync()) {
              return FittedBox(
                fit: BoxFit.contain,
                child: MeasureSize(
                  child: Image.file(img, key: imgKey),
                  onChange: (Size newSize) {
                    setState(() {
                      planSize = newSize;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              );
            } else
              return Container();
          }
        ),
      ),
      ...
```

Comment: won't this return the size of my fittedBox which seems to take up all the available space unlike the image which keeps its ratio?
if I put the key on the Fittedbox I get a size corresponding to MediaQuery.of(context).size minus the margin of 30 in height. I wouldn't have the same problem that way?

Comment: In that case I guess you can move the fitted box out of the MeasureSize widget. Check my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

thanks @Dennis Mwea for your time and solution, I just add the widget offset for my purpose but it's perfect.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

typedef void OnWidgetSizeChange(Size size, Offset pos);

class MeasuredWidget extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  final OnWidgetSizeChange onChange;

  const MeasuredWidget({Key? key, required this.onChange, required Widget child}) : super(key: key, child: child);

  @override
  RenderObject createRenderObject(BuildContext context) => _MeasureWidgetRenderObject(onChange);
}

class _MeasureWidgetRenderObject extends RenderProxyBox {
  Size? oldSize;
  Offset? oldPos;

  final OnWidgetSizeChange onChange;

  _MeasureWidgetRenderObject(this.onChange);

  @override
  void performLayout() {
    super.performLayout();

    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_){ 
      Size newSize = child!.size;
      Offset newPos = child!.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
      if (oldSize == newSize && oldPos == newPos) return;
      oldSize = newSize;
      oldPos = newPos;
      onChange(newSize, newPos));
  }
}
```